# Managing code base in HA infrastructure

Tags: performance

I'm wondering what people have found to be the best method for managing magento's code base in a HA cloud / auto scaling environment.  I'm currently planning to share the media directory over NFS, using AWS's CDN to cache both the CMS and product images.

Whilst NFS would make managing the code base simple, i figure the amount of extra network traffic would slow things down (even though varnish will be caching what content it can).  We deploy code from github, so i figure webhooks could be an option, but managing these with servers automatically coming on and off line could be tricky.

Any experience, thoughts, must avoids would be very greatly received.

*After thought:  Would like to experiment with the performance difference when using mage compiler too, which could make managing a 'synced' code base more challenging / need some more clever scripting.

Comment: Possibly relevant to your interests: http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/459/running-magento-in-an-aws-environment

Comment: Thanks @AlanStorm, read that one earlier tonight, but looking for ways to deal with the full on code base specifically.  The Angrybirds method of deploying a full new set of infrastructure seems pretty smart but slightly out of my budget / resource availability!

Answer (score 2):

The [deploy resource in Chef](http://docs.opscode.com/resource_deploy.html) is a good tool for managing deployments. My use case is self-hosted Chef Server version 10.18 installed on a utility host that manages my production, staging, and preview clusters. Here are the steps performed through a custom shell script:

> 1. Initialize variables
> 2. Get the latest revision hash from GitHub
> 3. Disable availability monitoring to prevent alerts over HTTP 503 status
> 4. Switch all web and utility hosts to maintenance mode (optional)
> 5. Deploy utility routines
>
>    1. Stop Magento’s cron and all Resque workers
>    2. Address filesystem dependencies
>    3. Chef checks out the defined revision as a new release
>    4. Address Magento dependencies (install packages, configure modman, configure local.xml)
>    5. Update all cron tasks and scripts for automation (paths, timing, arguments)
>    6. Deploy all modules (modman)
>    7. Clear cache (n98-magerun.phar)
>    8. Run any migrations (n98-magerun.phar)
>    9. Start the Magento cron (Chef `cron_d` resource)
>    10. Start Resque workers (Chef `execute` resource)
> 6. Deploy the first web host
>
>    1. Address filesystem dependencies (create directories: `chown` and then `chmod`)
>    2. Chef checks out the defined revision as a new release
>    3. Address Magento dependencies (install packages, configure modman, configure local.xml)
>    4. Deploy all Magento modules (modman)
> 7. Mark a new deployment in New Relic
> 8. Enable availability monitoring services
> 9. Disable load balancer services to all other web hosts
> 10. Continue deployments on web hosts, sequentially bringing them online
> 11. Perform Chef routines for the search hosts

Chef deploy [callbacks](http://docs.opscode.com/resource_deploy.html#callbacks) are also used to define an order of operations; commands fire only if the prior steps succeed.