# What is the procedure to setup Magento in Amazon web host?

Tags: server-setup, amazon-web-services, hosting

I want to set up my system using Amazon Web Services as a hosting provider. Can anyone help me with the follow:

- What is a good starting point for setting up an AWS box?
- How can I configure AWS to work with Magento?

Please help me

Comment: AWS is for top 5%/1% stores, it is high cost and low performance, there are various reasons why companies like this environent but you need a high end architecture to make the most of it. If you want more value you have mid-range which is Rackspace, or low cost high performance which is Digital Ocean. We license our architecture which runs on all these platforms, however unless you are spending $100s/mth (and this is low) you will not get any value out of AWS. You can use the bitnami Magento AMI, but expect over 5s page loads with it - you need sub 3s otherwise you lose 56% of visitors.

Comment: Please check this link

http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/459/running-magento-in-an-aws-environment


Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For a good starting point I recommend taking a look at a combination of the following tools:

1. [Vagrant](http://www.vagrantup.com/)
2. [Puppet](http://puppetlabs.com/)
3. [PuPHPet](https://puphpet.com/) - this is a GUI interface for configuring the above two tools. It's ridiculously easy to use.

Using the above links you can configure your AWS box and spin one up in no time.

**Note:** If you are serious about running a Magento site on AWS you need to talk to a professional AWS partner. In Australia we have companies like [Bulletproof](http://www.bulletproof.net.au/managed-cloud/managed-aws/managed-aws-magento/), a quick Google search will be able to help you find someone similar in your location.

Answer (score 1):

We have created a Magento AMI on AWS you can use the pre-configured image.
Configuration:
Magento 2.0.7
Php 7.0.7 with all required extension.
HTTPd 2.4
Already configured cron jobs for Magento2

[Scalable Magento2 stack AMI for online store on AWS](http://www.ipragmatech.com/products/scalable-magento2-stack-ami/)

Answer (score 0):

It might be late, but for somoone reference....We have recently hosted magento on AWS....We used pre-configured image provided by bitnami and it worked well....

https://aws.amazon.com/marketplace/pp/B007OUYR4Y

Answer (score 0):

Rackspace is quickly becoming an AWS provider. [I know as we've migrated and so many of my customers. Reduced our billing by more than 50%.] Don't get me wrong, Rackspace is very decent, mostly because of their excellent customer support, but the main disadvantage is cost.

- For DIY, AWS exceeds on all aspects and is the most flexible.

For example, for a proper starting point for Magento, you'll need a dev server and a prod server, and use GIT for source control. [the basics]

Even in a LAMP setup, you can stop your dev EC2 instance when not in use! That is huge cause you can't do that on Rackspace and many other hosting providers. Trust me, creating a sizeable image in Rackspace can take more than an hour.

- [aMi STACX turnkey Magento CE 2.1.x](https://magento.awsamistacks.com/)

For a turnkey AMI for Magento, aMi STACX is excellent for a small footprint t-small - t-large, Magento CE 2.1.x LAMP, and scores 100% on default theme pingdom tests. We use these and so do our customers. Problems we have encountered with other turnkey AMIs is they customize the install and LAMP paths, causing a lot of issues during in-app upgrades.

Happy e-commerce all :)