# Magento sessions in AWS Dynamodb

Tags: magento-enterprise, sessions, amazon-web-services, aws

in reference to this old post ([Running Magento in an AWS Environment](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/459/running-magento-in-an-aws-environment/)) by @Alan Storm, I see a lot of you mentioning using DynamoDB for magento sessions.

I have searched high and low, but I cannot find how to actually use it from Magento, just mentions of using it. As far as I know, it is not directly supported by Magento, or am I wrong?

I was going to experiment integrating it, <strike>but I am still stuck trying to create a DynamoDB table in AWS to the exact specifications required for the sessions table</strike>, I found this link with some specifications for the table (http://www.sitepoint.com/amazon-dynamodb-store-php-sessions-with-load-balancer/). Still, considering more than one person has mentioned it, I cannot believe there is no single document describing how to do it with Magento.

Is there anywhere documented how to easily integrate Magento with AWS DynamoDB? Or it's time to market a new module?

thanks!

NOTE - sdk for dynamodb sessions - http://docs.aws.amazon.com/aws-sdk-php/v2/guide/feature-dynamodb-session-handler.html

Comment: I believe that using Redis to store sessions has become the preferred option. In my opinion it's faster than storing in a db

Comment: HI Rudi, storing sessions in Redis is what we've been doing for the past 5 years or so, the usage of DynamoDB is the new part. I have heard good things about it, but can't find a validated setup with Magento yet.

Comment: Oh I see ! I will keep an eye out on this post, sounds very interesting, sorry I couldn't help

Comment: no problem. I hope someone can! :)