# Hosting Magento on AWS

Tags: hosting, aws

I am using Magento 1.9.0.1. My store has 15K+ SKUs and everyday I am getting 500+ sessions. Some time the session reaches 25K+

The SKUs are expected to reach 250K and per day user sessions 10K by next month.
My current hosting cannot handle this traffic and the site is being too slow. So I was thinking to shift it to **AWS**.

I search a lot about this but couldn't understand which Linux instance will suit my needs.
Can I please get some suggestions.

Comment: https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/459/running-magento-in-an-aws-environment

Comment: You might want AWS, but you need a managed service provider. AWS is for experienced system administrators (or teams of) who can build, monitor and operate their platform without needing support, guidance or help. In the context of what you need, AWS provides nothing other than abstraction, confusion and expense. If you are struggling to pick a distribution, you aren't anywhere near ready of building your own infrastructure and self-supporting it.

Comment: while you can find lots of information in that answer, but at the end you will have to test it yourself.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the AMI from Amazon and you can use this script to install your Magento instance

https://github.com/brentwpeterson/server-utilities/blob/master/amazon/aws-php54-percona56.sh

You should choose a t2.medium or m3.large to start. I prefer to use RDS for the database but it depends on your budget. You can also use Elastic cache if you want to add even more.

The servers run great and we have clients with 500k sku's using Amazon boxes.